# Sorting Object Array from another Object Array JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have bellow two object arrays

```
var array_1 = [{"Product_Name" : "p1"},{"Product_Name" : "p2"},{"Product_Name" : "p3"}]
var array_2 = [{"Product_Name" : "p5"},{"Product_Name" : "p1"},{"Product_Name" : "p3"},{"Product_Name" : "p2"},{"Product_Name" : "p4"}]
```

as you can see my second array is not in the order as first array. im trying to order second array as same as array 1.

i use bellow code but getting the result

```
function mapOrder (array, order, key) {

array.sort( function (a, b) {
var A = a[key], B = b[key];

if (order.indexOf(A) == order.indexOf(B)) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return -1;
}

});

return array;
};

var item_array, item_order, ordered_array;
item_array = array_2;
item_order = array_1;
ordered_array = mapOrder(item_array, item_order, 'Product_Name');
```

any suggestions get the second array as bellow

```
var array_2 = [{"Product_Name" : "p1"},{"Product_Name" : "p2"},{"Product_Name" : "p3"},{"Product_Name" : "p4"},{"Product_Name" : "p5"}]
```

Comment: You have a invalid object structure please fix that.

Comment: @CodeManiac fixed sorry about that. just over looked it

Comment: the two arrays have a different number of elements. How do you expect p4 and p5 to be handled? If the two arrays have the same number of elements, and the same element values, you could get the index of the target value (current value in array2) in array1, then swap it with the element that occupies that correct index the until you achieve the same order.

Comment: @JGof basically i want second array to be in the same order as array one. any element extra in array 2 should come bellow

Comment: what do you mean by "come below"?

Comment: @JGof so first three products should be in the same order as array one followed by p4 and p5 or p5 and p4.  order of extra element can be in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gets the target index based on the target array and swaps it with the value currently in that index. This code is not complete, so you'll have to add more logic to rectify the remnants of this simple in-place sorting.

```js
var array_1 = [{"Product_Name" : "p1"},{"Product_Name" : "p2"},{"Product_Name" : "p3"}]
var array_2 = [{"Product_Name" : "p5"},{"Product_Name" : "p1"},{"Product_Name" : "p3"},{"Product_Name" : "p2"},{"Product_Name" : "p4"}]

function btoa(a, b, key){
  b.map((m,from_ind)=> {
    let to_ind = a.findIndex((target)=>target[key] == m[key])
    if(from_ind != to_ind && to_ind >= 0) {
        let temp = b[to_ind];
        b[to_ind] = m;
        b[from_ind] = temp;
    }

  })

  console.log(b)
  return b
}

btoa(array_1, array_2, "Product_Name");
```